# Magento javascripts where are they loading from?

Tags: magento

I'm working on Magento installation that is causing me frustration.

I CAN find what seems to be the correct `page.xml` file loading the theme's Javascript (i.e prototype, scriptaculous, etc) in the header, but editing this file and removing scripts does not do ANYTHING for me.  When I try and remove/add any new scripts, nothing happens.

Maybe a cache issue?  But I have deleted all files from the cache folder.  I also tried to find the "Cache Management" menu in Admin, but there is not one there.

I'm 99% confident that I have looked in all of the folders that would call all Javascript.

I am new to Magento, so maybe I've missed something completely.

Any suggestions on where I could find where the basic scripts would be loading from?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I got it right. But what you want to know is the directory where the file .js is located, correct?

Try looking in: yourdomain/skin/frontend/yourtheme/default/js/

or: yourdomain/skin/frontend/default/yourtheme/js/

Comment: I already know where the actual scripts are located, but when I edit the .xml file to remove them, they are still being called.  That is why I'm so confused here :(

Comment: You try remove the link direct in the head file?

Answer (score 0):

Page.xml is the correct file you need to modify. If not a caching issue, the only other thing I can think of is you have a theme installed but trying to modify the default(base) page.xml.